# Java + Cloudflare - Prevent download requests for a certain url being 'blocked'?

Tags: java, cloudflare

I'm wondering how i'd go about allowing a connection from a Java application totally bypass cloudflare for my site. I've disabled browser integrity checks for my RSS feed connections which has allowed those through, but whenever cloudflare is active, when clicking the 'Play Now' button to update the client, it'll go grey, as it should, then remain like that. No errors or 404/403 errors are printed upon it doing this, and the client will not download.

The only thing that totally resolves this is pausing cloudflare and fully disabling it for my site. I've tried adding these rules for the download url, none of which have solved it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do it with the free plan **with page rules**.

Maybe you can do it by using a subdomain and disable the "Orange Cloud", so traffic will bypass any CloudFlare setting (CloudFlare will just give the IP of the server).

Or instead you can set "Security level: Off", but it's only for Enterprise Plan, and I'm not sure if you can make a Page Rule with it, because at least for the Free Plan (what I'm using) the "Off" value don't appear in the Page Rule config.